# How to change a word in a h2 when certain page is clicked on

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change a certain word in the title of a page dynamically with javascript depending on which link in the nav is clicked on. So for instance, if the "Asia" link is clicked I want the h2 to display: "You are in Asia" or if the "Europe link is clicked I want the h2 to say: "You are in Europe."

The html for the nav bar:

```
<div id="zone-nav">
<a href="" id="surge-btn"</a>
<a href="" id="latin-btn"</a>
<a href="" id="africa-btn"</a>                  
<a href="" id="asia-btn"</a>                    
</div>
```

The html I have thus far for the title that needs to be changed: `

```
<h2 id="zoneName">You are in<span id="zoneName"></span></h2>`
```

I know I need to write a function to determine what link is pressed, but I am a little confused on how to approach this.

Comment: If your links do what they're supposed to, they'll take you to a new page, so any `script` would be just useless?

Comment: Note you can't have item's with the same **id**. Also you are going to need to prevent the default behavior of an anchor tag (make a click event and return false).

Comment: `<a onclick="document.getElementById('zoneName').innerText = this.innerText">Asia</a>` ?

Comment: It's a Wordpress theme, so it's just one page of html with different content that needs to be displayed at certain times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to deal with your duplicate **id** here:

```
<h2 id="zoneName">You are in<span id="zoneName"></span></h2>
```

Note we cannot have the same **id** otherwise we don't know how to get an element by it's **id**. So remove the uneeded one on the `h2`:

```
<h2>You are in <span id="zoneName"></span></h2>
```

Then add event's to your `a` tags:

```
<div id="zone-nav">
    <a onclick="update('Surge')" id="surge-btn" >item1</a>
    <a onclick="update('Latin')" id="latin-btn" >item2</a>
    <a onclick="update('Africa')" id="africa-btn" >item3</a>                  
    <a onclick="update('Asia')" id="asia-btn" >item4</a>                    
</div>
```

*Note:* This can be done purely in JavaScript or be done easily in jQuery. But since you did not mention it I will not be using jQuery. We could iterate through by *ClassName* and have the links be a *class*, but that's no more simple then the way above.

For the JavaScript we need to `return false` to prevent the default behavior of a anchor tag:

```
function update(text) {
    document.getElementById("zoneName").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
}
```

**[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uwa36z2/1/)**

---

***Would there be a way to keep the updated text in the  even if the page reloads?***

Yes there is a way to do this without having to use a server-sided language. What I will do is use HTML 5 [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), note this will only work for browsers that support HTML 5 (which is all of the modern ones), you can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) if you need support for older browsers that work similarly for the following example. In this case I will be using `sessionStorage` which saves the information even until the browser is closed.

I will *emulate* a `href` to the same page for the `<a>` tags, we need to do this because we need to save out information before we move to a new page. After I save I will call `location.reload()` that will act as a refresh. Note that you could make this move to an entirely new page as well, just include the script on the new page and use `window.location.href = "newPageUrl"` ( *jsfiddle* prevents me from moving to a new page ).

The HTML will be the same but the JavaScript will be updated as followed:

```
window.onload = function() { // When the page loads
    if(sessionStorage.zoneName) { // Check if the session exist
        // update the page with the session info
        document.getElementById("zoneName").innerHTML = sessionStorage.zoneName; 
    }
}

function update(text) {
    sessionStorage.zoneName = text; // store the text into a session called "zoneName"
    location.reload(); // reload the page
    return;
}
```

**[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn073r03/7/)**

Comment: Awesome! I'm about to give this a shot.

Comment: Ok, this works, but when the link is clicked the page is being refreshed and there goes the name of the country. Another thing, the guy who actually made this website used images for the nav links, so I'm having to "display:none" the text which pretty much breaks this method.

Comment: Alright then we can give a string to the parameters of the method. I'll change that in an edit, although the page should not be refreshing.

Comment: Well it's linking to a specific page on the site, which is causing it to refresh. I should have mentioned that earlier, my fault!

Comment: Would there be a way to keep the updated text in the <h2> even if the page reloads?

Comment: @JacobCarpenter Yes there is but it's a completely different approach. When you load a new page the browser have no knowledge of the previous page (even if it was the same one). So what you need to do is save it in web storage be either a cookie or with HTML web storage (`localStorage` or `sessionStorage`). So when something is clicked you save it in web storage and retrieve on the new page. I can provide you with an example if you want.

Comment: An example would be tremendous. Thanks @SpencerWieczorek for all of your help thus far.

Comment: I've actually found a way to do it using php. Thanks for all of your help though @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @JacobCarpenter Yeah this is more of a job for a server-side lanugage like PHP. Although I didn't know that you where using PHP. Anyways I've updated my answer to show you how to do this with just JavaScript.

Comment: Well I have 0 knowledge of php, but since this is a Wordpress site, the theme is using tons of php. I dug into some of the code already on there and found that it was executing a chunk of code for this exact issue already, just for something a little different. Anyways, the edit you made is great. I never knew you could do such things as that. Thank you for teaching me many new things today sir!

Answer (score 1):

if you add some extra markup to your html, you can use a single jQuery event handler:

```
<div id="zone-nav">
 <a class="zone-select" href="" id="surge-btn">Surge?</a>
 <a class="zone-select" href="" id="latin-btn">Latin</a>
 <a class="zone-select" href="" id="africa-btn">Africa</a>                  
 <a class="zone-select" href="" id="asia-btn">Asia</a>                    
</div>
```

now the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".zone-select").on("click", function() {
        $("#zoneName").html($(this).html());
    };
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I added the following jQuery in the header of the page and nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: like a few people mentioned, you need to remove the zoneName id from the h2 element, just leave it on the span

Comment: Spencer had a more complete answer than I had, give his a shot.

Comment: Yes I also fixed that issue: <h2>Adopt a Pastor in<span id="zoneName"></span></h2> I'm new to jQuery so is there a way to check if the jQuery is actually being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you could do for the `africa-btn` (this will require jQuery, I hope that's alright):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#africa-btn").on("click", function() {
        $("#zoneName").html("Africa");
    };
    // Other buttons here
});
```

What this is doing is attaching an action to the "click" event of the `africa-btn` anchor tag. When it's clicked it should update the span's html as described above. You can add further click events in a similar way.

Using `$("#africa-btn")` to bind the click event is a way to do it specifically for that one button, so you'll have to do it for each id.

Comment: For a non-jQuery solution, if wanted, you can use a call like this: `document.getElementById("zoneName").innerHTML = "Africa"` in your event listener.

Answer (score 0):

This would update the selected zone in the dom

```
   <div id="zone-nav">
    <a id="africa-btn" onclick="updateZone('africa'); return false;"> </a>                  
    <a id="asia-btn" onclick="updateZone('asia'); return false;"> </a>                    
   </div>

   function updateZone(countryName){
       document.getElementById('zoneName').innerText = countryName;
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: Don't forget the return false.

Answer (score -1):

are you looking for something like this :

Simple html and javascript only:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9L37c32/

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('zoneName_replace').innerHTML='Asia'">Asia</a>
```

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting